# Unable to resolve com.github.corda.crash:crash.shell:jar:9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716 when building CORDA using MAven

Tags: dependencies, corda

I am trying to build a corda node from IDE using MAVEN. 
I get the following dependency failure .
Downloading: https://nexus:8443/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/corda/crash/crash.parent/9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716/crash.parent-9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716.pom Downloading: https://nexus:8443/nexus/content/repositories/unmanaged_releases/com/github/corda/crash/crash.parent/9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716/crash.parent-9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716.pom Downloading: https://nexus:8443/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/bft-smart/library/master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87/library-master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87.pom Downloading: https://nexus:8443/nexus/content/repositories/unmanaged_releases/com/github/bft-smart/library/master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87/library-master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87.pom [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time: 0.974 s [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2018-01-24T11:28:16-06:00 [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Final Memory: 15M/309M [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal on project bdl-corda: Could not resolve dependencies for project :
 Failed to collect dependencies at net.corda:corda-node-driver:jar:2.0.0 -> net.corda:corda-test-utils:jar:2.0.0 -> net.corda:corda-node:jar:2.0.0 -> com.github.corda.crash:crash.shell:jar:9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.corda.crash:crash.shell:jar:9d242da2a10e686f33a3aefc69e4768824ad0716: Could not transfer artifact com.github.corda.crash:crash.parent:pom:9d242da2

I do not see that jar in maven central . Is there another maven URL for this ? Any help would be appreciated.

dependencies from pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-finance</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-rpc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-node-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-node-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which project have you opened in your IDE? What are you clicking/running to build a node?

Comment: I have my own project . I copied the code from NodeDriver.java from corda-sample . I am running mvn clean install

Comment: Does it work if you run the example CorDapp? See https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html.

Comment: gradle build works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it took me forever to find the solution. The problem is that these artifacts are in a different repository than the rest. You will need to add the following to your pom:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft</id>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```